# Internet not working while Using Router as Repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I belive this would be an easy one for the community but I am not able to get my head around it.

I have a network of Tp-Link Deco Wi-Fi extenders linked to my main router and that is working fine.

Now, I am trying to connect my D-link router in Repeater mode to this extended network (not to the original one as there is no range). I am trying to connect via WiFi as I cannot get cable to this point.

I did everything and went to few tutorials but the problem is that my D-link network is not getting Internet.

While setting up I tried giving the IP 192.168.68.2 which is in the range of Default gateway of Tp-Link Extender's 192.168.68.1 with no luck.

I have connected this D-link router before in another network. But not sure what I am doing wrong now!

Is it because I am working with already extended network and not with the source router?

Thoughts please!

Thanks, Rah.

Comment: Is that reference to 192.168.68.1 accurate?  Typically 192.168.0.xxx or 192.168.1.xxx are common addresses.

Comment: That's right. My main router has 192.168.1.1 but the Tp-Link extender has IP of 192.168.68.1

Comment: What's the point of starting a bounty and then abandoning the post?

Answer (score 1):

This is said to be possible, but you should be aware of the fact that each
extender can potentially halve the connection speed.
For example, if your home internet runs at 100 mbps, one range extender
feeding off the main router might reduce your throughput down to 50 mbps,
and then piggy-backing another extender might reduce the throughput even
further.

More optimal solutions are:

- Getting a stronger router and connecting both extenders to it directly
- Using Powerline adapters (if possible with your house wiring)
- Using WiFi Mesh Systems, as they use a superior technology.

Nevertheless, to piggyback two extenders, the main consideration is that both
extenders should not broadcast the same SSID as the main router.
This is the default setting, but people often set up extenders to broadcast the
same SSID to avoid the need to connect to multiple SSIDs.

With two extenders using the same SSID there is a risk of them connecting to
each other instead of to the main router or the nearest hop-point.

Assigning a static IP to each extender should also help the flow,
and they should be excluded from the IP pool of the DHCP server.

For the success of this setup and the over-all network speed that is possible,
much depends upon the quality of your extenders.

References:

- [Setting up WiFi extenders… is it possible to daisy-chain them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/457569/setting-up-wifi-extenders-is-it-possible-to-daisy-chain-them)
- [The Real Truth about Range Extenders](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/real-truth-range-extenders-greg-morrison/)
- [Ditch the Wi-Fi Extender: Why You Should Get a MeshPoint Instead](https://blog.amplifi.com/2017/04/25/ditch-the-wi-fi-extender-why-you-should-get-a-meshpoint-instead/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your main router assigns addresses via DHCP, your D-link router should have DHCP disabled, so that your main router assigns all ip addresses.

Comment: Once I use the Repeater option in the D-Link router, it disables the DHCP. This video will give some idea on how I am trying to set up my D-Link router. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrnMCdmWlwg&ab_channel=AFTechHouse

Comment: Can a PC near the D-Link see either of the routers, using the well-known **ping** command, even if you can't get all the way through to the internet?

Comment: When I am connecting to the D-Link using it's WiFi, I am able to ping the IP address I have set - 192.168.68.2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do that with my M5 deco routers, even called the vendor and it seems like it was not supported to have a wifi mesh setup mixed with a ethernet backhauled extender.  I recently purchased an additional m9 and I was able to add that one with an ethernet backhaul to my existing mesh.  I just had to swap out my main deco m5 with an m9 first.  is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do this with my Deco AC1200 routers. I have two of them in the network. Working perfectly fine. The IP I mentioned in the question 192.168.68.1 is of the deco network.
Now, I am trying to connect another router - D-Link Dir-600M with the Deco network which is not working (D-Link is not getting internet).